# Gradle compiler plugin

Tags: gradle

I need to add a compiler plugin in gradle, I know how to do it in maven:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.7.0</version>
<configuration>
    <compilerArgs>
        <arg>--add-modules</arg>
        <arg>java.xml.bind</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
</configuration>
```

how to do the same in gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(['--add-modules', 'java.xml.bind']) 
}
```

See [JavaCompile.options](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile:options) and [CompilerOptions.compilerArgs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:compilerArgs)